# MFC: allow docking to main view

Tags: mfc, docking

In Visual Studio, you can dock arbitrary panes to the main view in the center of the window:[image]

In the above image, the Error List pane is being docked to the main view.

I'd like to do that with CDockablePanes in MFC. However, it appears that by default, docking panes to the main view isn't allowed. Is this possible with MFC? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panes are normally docked to the `CMainFrame`, and they can be docked above the main view.

If you need to dock them *inside your view* they should be created (and docked to) in the `CChildFrame`.

Make sure to use `.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);` and `EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);`

---

In case you are referring to **converting a dockable pane to a tabbed document**, right click on the pane header and select '`Tabbed Document`'.

Also check out [`CDockablePane::ConvertToTabbedDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc665442.aspx) and [`m_bCanCovertControlBarToMDIChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984330.aspx).

Comment: On what classes do I need to call EnableDocking() on?

Comment: @josmith42 - `EnableDocking()` is called in `CMainFrame::OnCreate()`, or in `CChildFrame` if you want the panels there.

Comment: It looks like m_bCanConvertControlBarToMDIChild is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @josmith42 - No problem. Glad to help.